# Are constant acceleration and zero acceleration same? If they are different, in what context?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

If initial velocity is 5 m/sec and acceleration is zero, then the body moves with a constant velocity 5 m/sec. The graph is a horizontal straight line(v=u+at). However, my question is how a body moves with a constant velocity without acceleration. In a velocity-time graph, whether a horizontal straight line indicates a zero acceleration or constant acceleration?

Comment: In a graph of $v(t)$, a horizontal line means zero acceleration. Any other straight line means constant acceleration. In a graph of $x(t)$, straight lines indicate zero acceleration. Parabolas indicate constant acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

Constant acceleration means that the acceleration does not change.

Some would say that if the acceleration is zero then the acceleration does not change and so one can say that the acceleration is constant.
What others would say is that if there is no acceleration it is meaningless to qualify what type of acceleration it is as it does not exist.

I favour the first statement although I cannot remember using the phrase "moving with a constant zero acceleration" instead of "moving with zero acceleration" where in the second phrase the word "constant" is implied in the same way as when stating that the acceleration is $4 \, \rm m\, s^{-2}$ or $-4 \, \rm m\, s^{-2}$.

Comment: Great answer! I would just add that it can be also constant and negative, because all the examples in the answers have positive accelerations.

Comment: @ccorbella Thank you for you comment and I have amended my answer to incorporate it.

Comment: Suppose a car is moving @5 m/sec at each time interval of 1 sec, then how the car is moving with zero acceleration can attain this constant velocity. It has to come to a stop due to gravity.

Comment: @MathivananPalraj The car would have to accelerate from rest and if it then had a constant velocity its acceleration would be zero.

Comment: Therefore, the initial acceleration(constant) would continue in order to keep the car moving with constant velocity, right. Hence, zero acceleration means there is no change in initial acceleration.

Comment: @MathivananPalraj I am sorry but I do not understand what you have written. The only time that you can have a constant velocity and a constant acceleration is when the acceleration is zero.

Comment: Without acceleration a body cannot be in motion. The acceleration can be increased or decreased or kept constant for a desired motion of a body. With zero acceleration the body will come to a stop due to gravity. If you want a quick stop we can decelerate the body. In the equation v=u+at, 'a' should indicate the change in initial acceleration. If there is no change, a=0; the body continues its motion with the same velocity. The equation can be framed as v=u+delta a*t.

Answer (score 0):

Zero acceleration is zero. It's different from constant acceleration as the latter means any value >0 or <0 **but not equal to 0**. From the graph, if there would have been constant acceleration, the graph would have been different. So, although zero is a constant, zero acceleration is zero acceleration, not constant acceleration.

Comment: Really negative acceleration cannot be constant?

Answer (score 0):

Relative to a "fixed point", $\frac {\mathrm{change \, in\, location}}{\mathrm{time}} $ is a velocity (vector). $\frac {\mathrm{Change \, in \, velocity}}{\mathrm{time}} = $ acceleration.  For acceleration to be zero, there can be no change in velocity. For acceleration to be constant, the $\frac {\mathrm{Change \, in \, velocity}}{\mathrm{time}} $ must be constant.  This means $V_1 - V_0 = V_2 - V_1 = \, \cdots = \Delta V = $ constant.  Of course a $\Delta V = 0$ can be a constant as well.